# What is the difference in the following vector creations?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

```
vector<int>myvec;
```

and

```
vector<int>myvec[20];
```

When i tried to do a standard push_back operation in second case`(myvec.push_back(41))`i got a compile error.
I think i need to mention the position where `41` needs to be inserted i this case.Am I right?

Comment: One is an array of vectors the other isnt... [Maybe this will help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: You probably meant the second example to be `vector<int> myvec(20);` which creates a vector of 20 ints.

Answer (score 7):

The second declaration does not create a single vector, it creates an array of 20 vectors.  You would have to do `myvec[0].push_back(...)` instead, to add an element to the first vector in the array.